# Join with multiple options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am attempting to return a record set based on if the user is related to a building in one or more ways in LINQ and am having alot of trouble with this.

Basically, I need to show all users who exist within the same building body corporate or they are a tennant in the building.

This will also be filtered by an Array of building IDs. In my example I hard code the building Arrays (2, 4, 6) but this will need to be some form of .Contains()

I have written the query that I need in standard SQL and it workes perfectly. I am having alot of trouble converting this to LINQ.

Could somebody please explain the best way to do something like this in linq would be, or suggest a way I am able to convert standard SQL into entitys?

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    UserProfile UP
WHERE 
    EXISTS(
    SELECT 
        BodyCorporateMemberID 
    FROM 
        BodyCorporateMembers BCM 
    WHERE 
        UP.UserId = BCM.UserId AND BCM.BuildingId IN (2, 4, 6)
    )
    OR
    EXISTS(
    SELECT 
        UR.UserRoomId
    FROM 
        UserRoom UR
        INNER JOIN Rooms R ON UR.RoomId = R.RoomId
        INNER JOIN Floors F ON R.FloorId = F.FloorId
    WHERE
        UR.UserId = UP.UserId AND F.BuildingId IN (2, 4, 6)
    )
```

Comment: Do you already have a model in EF? could you show it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to fix it and it was not as hard As i thought, although i have been struggling with it for a few hours. I'm still not convinced that this is an optimal way to do it, but the preformance should be sufficent for what i need it for

```
var buildings = Functions.getBodyCorporateBuildings(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);

var userprofilemodel =
(from u in db.UserProfiles
where
(
(
    from BCM in db.BodyCorporateMembers
    where u.UserId == BCM.UserId && buildings.Contains(BCM.BuildingId)
    select new { HasBodyCorporate = true }
).Any()
||
(
    from UR in db.UserRoom
    join R in db.Room on UR.RoomId equals R.RoomId
    join F in db.Floor on R.FloorId equals F.FloorId
    where UR.UserProfileId == u.UserId && buildings.Contains(F.BuildingId)
    select new { HasRoom = true }
).Any()
)
orderby u.FirstName, u.LastName
select new UserListViewModel
{
    UserId = u.UserId
}).ToPagedList(page, 10);
```